# Finding ideal number of clusters in R

Tags: r, clustering

[image: https://imgur.com/a/DEYfxPQ]

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAJtm.jpg

[Link to dataset](https://filebin.net/ger70h7pk0kf58gr)

Above is a picture of the results, a picture of the actual data and then a link for the excel file of the actual data.

I want to work out what the ideal number of clusters is for this data set.
I am unsure how to go about finding this ideal number of clusters, simply from reading the excel file I would guess 7 clusters because the ratings are all in the range (3-9). However when I plot them using plotcluster, anything higher than 4 clusters has quite a large overlap.

I have tried scaling the data using:

`data.train <- scale(wine[-12])`

and used 12 as it is the rating column which I believe is what we are categorising on.

`nc <- NbClust(data.train,min.nc=2, max.nc=15,method="kmeans")`

Also this code simply never loads as the data is most likely too large.

```
wine<-read.csv("whitewine_dataset.csv")  
data.train <- scale(wine[-12])
wss <- 0
for (i in 1:15){
  wss[i] <-sum(kmeans(data.train, centers=i)$withinss)
}
plot(1:15,wss,type="b",xlab="Number of Clusters",ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
```

```
fit.km <- kmeans(data.train, 4)
library(fpc)
plotcluster(data.train, fit.km$cluster)
```

I am unsure of how to read this graph or whether the results even mean anything.

Something I expected would be like this, but this is from another data set and using the `NbClusters` function

```
Among all indices:
* 2 proposed 2 as the best number of clusters
* 13 proposed 3 as the best number of clusters
* 5 proposed 4 as the best number of clusters
* 1 proposed 6 as the best number of clusters
* 2 proposed 10 as the best number of clusters
***** Conclusion *****
*According to the majority rule, the best number of clusters is 3
```

Comment: this question might be better for stat exchange because it seems more of a mathematical problem than coding. also you could try to do a factor analysis to determine clusters based on eigenvalues

Comment: What if there are **no clusters**? At least none that can be found by k-means?

Comment: I might recommend trying out a model-based clustering approach. Checkout the mclust package in R. K-means clusters using centroids. Mclust allows you to test a number of different model structures that include multiple properties of the cluster-specific posterior multivariate distributions. Happy to post a more complete mini-walkthrough if you are interested. But if you search for their documentation online I remember it being pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally many methods to find out optimal number of clusters in k-means clustering, and it also depends on the type of data you have and other statistical parameters of the data.

Below are some of the methods used to identify the optimal number of clusters in k-means clustering.

I am using a sample data set available at UCI, [UCI_Dataset_StudentKnowledge](https://redirect.viglink.com/?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_157193163441614&key=949efb41171ac6ec1bf7f206d57e90b8&libId=k24v415201021u9s000DAbojf1nyn&loc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.r-bloggers.com%2Ffinding-optimal-number-of-clusters%2F&v=1&out=https%3A%2F%2Farchive.ics.uci.edu%2Fml%2Fdatasets%2Fser%2BKnowledge%2BModeling%2BData%2B(Students%27%2BKnowledge%2BLevels%2Bon%2BDC%2BElectrical%2BMachines)%23&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&title=Finding%20Optimal%20Number%20of%20Clusters%20%7C%20R-bloggers&txt=UCI_Dataset_StudentKnowledge).
Some data preprocessing:

```
library(readr)
StudentKnowledgeData <- read_csv("YourdownloadFolderPath/StudentKnowledgeData.csv")
View(StudentKnowledgeData)

mydata  = StudentKnowledgeData
#analyze the data to find if categorical variables are there and if so
#transform them.
mydata = as.data.frame(unclass(mydata))
summary(mydata)
dim(mydata)
# We can now remove any records that have NAs
myDataClean = na.omit(mydata)
dim(myDataClean)
summary(myDataClean)
```

Output:

```
[1] 402   5
      STG              SCG              STR              LPR        
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0100   Min.   :0.0000  
 1st Qu.:0.2000   1st Qu.:0.2000   1st Qu.:0.2700   1st Qu.:0.2500  
 Median :0.3025   Median :0.3000   Median :0.4450   Median :0.3300  
 Mean   :0.3540   Mean   :0.3568   Mean   :0.4588   Mean   :0.4324  
 3rd Qu.:0.4800   3rd Qu.:0.5100   3rd Qu.:0.6800   3rd Qu.:0.6500  
 Max.   :0.9900   Max.   :0.9000   Max.   :0.9500   Max.   :0.9900
```

Elbow method to identify optimal K:

The elbow method looks at the percentage of variance explained as a function of the number of clusters: One should choose a number of clusters so that adding another cluster doesn’t give much better modeling of the data. More precisely, if one plots the percentage of variance explained by the clusters against the number of clusters, the first clusters will add much information (explain a lot of variance), but at some point the marginal gain will drop, giving an angle in the graph. The number of clusters is chosen at this point, hence the “elbow criterion”. This “elbow” cannot always be unambiguously identified.

```
#Elbow Method for finding the optimal number of clusters
set.seed(123)
# Compute and plot wss for k = 2 to k = 15.
k.max <- 15
data <- scaled_data
wss <- sapply(1:k.max, 
              function(k){kmeans(data, k, nstart=50,iter.max = 15 )$tot.withinss})
wss
plot(1:k.max, wss,
     type="b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, 
     xlab="Number of clusters K",
     ylab="Total within-clusters sum of squares")
```

Output:

```
[1] 2005.0000 1635.8573 1416.7041 1253.9959 1115.4657 1026.0506  952.4835  887.7202
 [9]  830.8277  780.2121  735.6714  693.7745  657.0939  631.5901  608.3576
```

[image]

Therefore for k=4 the between_ss/total_ss ratio tends to change slowly and remain less changing as compared to other k’s.so for this data k=4 should be a good choice for number of clusters however k=5 also seems to be a potential candidate.

Comment: There is no elbow in this plot. Clearly, the clustering failed to produce good clusters for any k.